# Exclude subdirectory from rollup-plugin-copy (vite.js)

Tags: vite, rollupjs, pdftron

Im trying to integrate [pdftron](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/get-started/npm/) into an existing vite.js build.

As the mentioned in the link above, I copied all necessary assets into my output-folder.
But all the files sum up to more than 300MB. So I want to exclude some feature which I don't need. [The vendor ships a script for optimizing the library](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/optimizing-lib-folder/), but it's not possible to run the optimization script automated right now.

Anyhow, I want to mimic the behavior of the optimization script  by removing the biggest unnecessary folders from the build. But somehow I'm unable to exclude the subdirectories from beeing copied. I guess there is a very stupid mistake within my configuration. Below there is an extract from my `vite.config.js`. I tried multiple different ways of excluding the directory (as you can see it turned into a guessing game). Nothing worked so far.

If necessary, I will provide a demo project.

```
import copy from "rollup-plugin-copy";


const outputDir = 'build';
/**
 * @type {import('vite').UserConfig}
 */
const config = {
  build: {
    outDir: outputDir,
    emptyOutDir: false,
    assetsDir: '.',
    lib: {
      entry: 'index.js',
      name: 'my-lib',
      fileName: 'my-lib.js',
      formats: ['es']

    },

    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        entryFileNames: `my-lib.js`,
        chunkFileNames: `[name].js`,
        assetFileNames: `[name].[ext]`
      },
      plugins: [copy({
        targets: [
          {
            src: ['node_modules/@pdftron/webviewer/public/*', '!core/pdf/full/*'],
            dest: outputDir + '/pdftron1'
          },
          {
            src: ['node_modules/@pdftron/webviewer/public', '!node_modules/@pdftron/webviewer/public/core/pdf/full/*'],
            dest: outputDir + '/pdftron2'
          },
          {
            src: ['node_modules/@pdftron/webviewer/public', '!node_modules/@pdftron/webviewer/public/core/pdf/full'],
            dest: outputDir + '/pdftron3'
          },
          {
            src: ['node_modules/@pdftron/webviewer/public', '!node_modules/@pdftron/webviewer/public/core/pdf/full/'],
            dest: outputDir + '/pdftron4'
          },
          {
            src: ['node_modules/@pdftron/webviewer/public', '!node_modules/@pdftron/webviewer/public/core/pdf/full/**'],
            dest: outputDir + '/pdftron5'
          },
        ]
      })
      ]

    },

  },
}

export default config
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "pdftron-vite-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "vite build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@pdftron/webviewer": "8.7.0"
  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "vite": "^2.9.13",
    "rollup-plugin-copy": "^3.3.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation, I found a solution. This is my new `rollup-plugin-copy`-configuration

```
copy({
    targets: [
      {
        src: [
          'node_modules/@pdftron/webviewer/public/core/assets'
          , 'node_modules/@pdftron/webviewer/public/core/external'
          , 'node_modules/@pdftron/webviewer/public/core/pdf'
          , '!node_modules/@pdftron/webviewer/public/core/pdf/full'
          , 'node_modules/@pdftron/webviewer/public/core/*'
          , 'node_modules/@pdftron/webviewer/public/ui/assets'
          , 'node_modules/@pdftron/webviewer/public/ui/chunks'
          , 'node_modules/@pdftron/webviewer/public/ui/i18n'
          , 'node_modules/@pdftron/webviewer/public/ui/*'
        ],

        dest: outputDir,
        expandDirectories: true,
        onlyFiles: true,
      }
    ],
    flatten: false,
    hook: 'writeBundle'
  })
```

The solution is based on [this issue](https://github.com/vladshcherbin/rollup-plugin-copy/issues/47).

Notice [I changed the hook to `writeBundle`](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/1231), so vite will not delete everything when `emptyOutDir` is set to `true`.